# Angular Popup component doesn't allow access to confirmNo/confirmYes

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a Popup Component with some text, and a click handler, which works fine when I build in development (i.e. `ng build`). However, when I build in production (i.e. `ng build --prod`) I get the following errors:

```
ERROR in node_modules/ng2-opd-popup/components/popup/popup.component.html(9,76): Property 'confirmNo' is private and only accessible within class 'PopupComponent'.
node_modules/ng2-opd-popup/components/popup/popup.component.html(10,66): Property 'confirmYes' is private and only accessible within class 'PopupComponent'.
```

I followed the guide in the [Readme](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-opd-popup), but it does not build.

This is how my app.module.ts looks like:
...
import { PopupModule } from 'ng2-opd-popup';

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    ...
  ],
  entryComponents: [
    ...
  ],
  imports: [
    ...,
    PopupModule
  ],
  providers: [{
    ......
  }, ...],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
  exports: [
   ...
  ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

This is the Component:

```
import { Popup } from 'ng2-opd-popup';


@Component( {
  selector: 'app-admin',
  templateUrl: './admin.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './admin.component.scss' ]
} )
export class AdminComponent implements OnInit
{

  constructor ( public popup: Popup ) { }

  ngOnInit ()
  {

  }

  act() {
    alert('WORKS');
  }

  show() {


      this.popup.options = {
        header: 'TEST',
        confirmBtnContent: 'Yes',
        cancleBtnContent: 'No',
        confirmBtnClass: 'btn btn-default',
        cancleBtnClass: 'btn btn-default',
        animation: 'fadeInDown'
    };
      this.popup.show(this.popup.options);
  }

}
```

This is the HTML file

```
<h1>Test</h1>

        <button (click)="show()">Show</button>  

        <popup (confirmClick)='act()'>Are you sure you?</popup>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can't access private members in your templates if you want to use ahead-of-time compilation : All methods and properties in a component accessed by its template must be public in the compilation scenario so try to declare the confirmNo and confirmYes as public properties in your popup component or in the show method for your case i guess.
More details about compiler error acessing private properities [Here](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/11422)

Comment: The popup component is not mine - I just installed it. Regarding the properties it is complaining about, I do not use them. In my HTML, I only use confirmClick